# Power BI - Optimizing reports

Tags: azure, powerbi, business-intelligence

I am using Power BI embedded server tier A1 to host PBIX reports for my production environment. I have about one million rows being loaded into the reports with each refresh (pulling data from CSV files).

Currently, the memory consumption of the embedded server is always near 100%, memory thrashing is almost constantly 100%, the reports load very slowly (if at all), and the data refresh fails every single time (though it works fine from Power BI Desktop).

I cannot afford a higher tier embedded server so, what are my options for optimizing the current report and having it work properly with the A1 tier embedded server?

Comment: Optimizing is highly report specific. There may or may not be a resolution, but it's nearly impossible to say without actually seeing the report structure and calculations.

Comment: @AlexisOlson I was afraid this would be the case...what is the best way for me to share those details without revealing too much? I am only supporting the infrastructure, I did not design the report itself, so any help is appreciated.